# 3d polylines and polygons

Tags: topology

Is there a way to extract z values from a DEM into a polyline and/or polygon featurclass in arcmap 10? I would like to have 3d polylines and polygons to make cross sections in a CAD, but currently I have no way to project to a surface.

Answer (score 8):

Oops, I figured it out. In case anyone is wondering though:

3D Analyst Tools/Functional Surface/Interpolate Shape

Comment: **WARNING** After extracting elevation values to my feature classes I noticed multiple holes. I then realized that <null> values in my DEM which I had not seen simply erased parts of my polygons and lines. Done make the same mistake!